# Treatment to one-dimensional arrays as a[ (b=c) [index]]. What does it mean?

Tags: java, arrays

In test I faced following question:

```
    int[] a = {3, 2, 1, 0};
    int[] b = {12, 13, 14, 15};

    System.out.println(b[(b=a)[3]]); // ?
    System.out.println(b[3]); // ?
```

output:

```
12
0
```

Who can explain this result?

```
b[ (b=a) [3] ]
```

What is the construction means?

Comment: It gets executed as `b[a[3]]` and `a[3]`.

Comment: looks like the parenthesis `(b=a)` is giving it priority to assigning the values of a to b.  Then take the fourth value of this array `a[3]` (0 in this case) and use it as an index for the outer b[0] - so, at this point, it really looks like a[0] would be printed out (or the value 12) for the first line

Comment: This is a horrible test question.  It implies that writing such code would be acceptable in a real world application.

Comment: It means "obfuscated code".

Comment: I think it is question whis shows my 
understanding of arrays construction

Comment: But the question is not about array construction. It is about array *access*.

Comment: Looks like trying to make sure the person understands the order of evaluation and how to prioritize assignments - also understanding scope and copy by value vs reference :)

Comment: @blurfus The question tries to make sure you understand rules which will hopefully never be invoked in a real Java program. It is very useful to spend a lot of time banging your head against exactly those rules, especially when you are a beginner and there is a mountain of important real-world knowledge on the horizon before you.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik agreed. A real Java program (coded by a person who knows) hopefully would not get written this way as it makes it difficult to read and maintain.  However, the concepts to learn (scope, order of evaluation, etc) are building blocks that need to be understood fully (even in muddy situations like the code above) - the learner needs to know them (real or not) to avoid these pitfalls.

Comment: @blurfus My point is that there are priorities involved in acquiring your knowledge, and this one is *very* low priority. After 15 years of experience with Java I am still waiting for the day I am going to apply that particular piece of knowledge to a real-world problem. This is a puzzler, nothing more.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik again, agree with you. My point is that if the OP says it found this in a test, then perhaps is, as you indicate, a puzzler but one with the specific purpose of making sure the OP understands those building blocks (which we learned long, long time ago)

Comment: @blurfus Actually, I had never learned, or had a reason to learn, this until I encountered such questions as this one here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik According your rating you faced a huge similar puzzles

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I would venture to guess that you had to learn about variable scope, order of evaluation in a statements, assignment by value vs reference, etc. one way or another (perhaps never in a 'test' as the OP)

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, I did---and it all started just two years ago. I have acquired a whole lot of knowledge which is useless to me in any other respect except for giving answers to people who wonder about them.

Comment: @blurfus This is about evaluation order of array access expressions, and about the visibility of the effect of nested assignments. Much less convoluted questions are enough to ask about any one of the concepts you list. BTW I don't see any trace of variable scope here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik re: scope - if you move the assignment of `b=a` out to its own line (before the first print statement) you get a different result on the first print statement.  I'll let you figure out why...

Comment: @blurfus Not due to variable scope, let me assure you.

Comment: ok - I'll take that as your answer - maybe you can explain to me then why the assignment of (b=a) has no effect on the second print statement :)

Comment: What does this construction mean? It means you should fire the person who wrote this code.

Comment: But the assignment of `b=a` does have an effect on the second print statement. That assignment is the reason why the second statement prints 0 instead of 15.

Comment: Ooops, @blurfus, it's back to the classroom for you! :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik touche!

Comment: I guess I meant the outer array on that same first statement - whatevs!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you join links with other puzzles question?

Comment: @gstackoverflow I don't keep them around, so unfortunately not :) But there's a whole book by Josh Bloch called Java Puzzlers if you're into that. A related [presentation](http://strangeloop2010.com/system/talks/presentations/000/014/450/BlochLee-JavaPuzzlers.pdf) is publicly available.

Comment: thanks for interesting informations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just evaluate that expression left-to-right:

```
b[ (b=a) [3] ]
```

- First that is accessing an index in array `b`.
- Which index is being accessed is being decided by the expression inside `[]`:

  - `[(b=a)[3]]`
- Evaluating the expression inside:

  - First `b` reference is assigned the value of `a` reference. So, now `b` is referring to the array being referred to by `a`. That expression is effectively equivalent to:

    - `b = a`, followed by `[b[3]]`.

So, the original expression becomes:

```
b[a[3]] // == b[0] // == 12
```

Now, after the first expression, since `b` reference has changed to point to `a` array, the 2nd expression: `b[3]`, is same as: `a[3]`, which is `0`.

Comment: why b[...]  taken before (b=a) ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Because `(b = a)` expression is inside the array access expression.

Comment: @gstackoverflow The language specification states that the pieces of an expression are logically evaluated left-to-right. (This is ***unlike*** C and C++.)

Answer (score 0):

`b[ (b=a)[3] ]` means:

1. array `b` will have the same values of array `a` in this assignment `(b=a)`
2. After that, `(b=a)[3]` means return the 4<sup>th</sup> index of `b` which is zero(i.e array b have the same values of `a = {3, 2, 1, 0}`)
3. `b[(b=a)[3]]` means `b[0]` which is `12`.

Comment: In step 2, I think you meant to say the 4th index `a[3]` (instead of the 3rd index)